# Como usar o valor de um Future em flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Eu estou usando Flutter para criar uma aplicação em móvel com duas coleções no Cloud Firestore, a coleção `user` e a coleção `person`.

- A coleção `person` armazena a informação de todas as pessoas que se
  podem registar na app.
- A coleção `user` armazena a data do utilizador que se registou.

Eu quero utilizar a informação dentro dos documentos da coleção `user` para procurar por um documento na coleção `person`. Depois do utilizador se registar não consigo utilizar o nome do utilizador para realizar uma query na coleção `person`.

```
Future<String> getPersonName(userId) {
  Firestore.instance
      .collection('user')
      .document(userId)
      .get()
      .then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
  return  ds['Person Name'];
  }, onError: (error) {
    return error;
  }

  );
}

Future<String> getPersonData(personName, documentData) async {
  DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance
      .collection('person')
      .document(userId)
      .get();
  var name= snapshot.data[documentData];
  if (name is String) {
    return name;
  } else {
    return 'Empty';
  }
}
```

A função `getPersonName()` retorna um Future com o valor que quero usar na função `getPersonData()`

No meu `Scaffold` eu usei um `FutureBuilder` para mostrar a data.

```
    FutureBuilder(
        future: getPersonData(personName, 'Data'),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return Text(snapshot.data);
        }),
```

O Future retorna a informação correta

No `FutureBuilder` como posso aceder ao valor de `personName`? Já tentei várias opções e acabo sempre com um Future em vez do valor.

Comment: Onde fica a linha que você chama a função ```getPersonName()```?

Comment: Você parece ser novo no site... Então uma dica, não fique poluindo o mesmo com várias perguntas, você poderia apenas *EDITAR* essa sua outra [pergunta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/436781/return-a-value-from-future-on-flutter)!

Answer (score 1):

Você recebe sempre o Future porque você não está retornando corretamente os dados, no seu método `getPersonData()` você fez certo o uso do `async`, você só precisa arrumar o teu `getPersonName()` de acordo...

Modifique da seguinte maneira:

```
Future<String> getPersonName(userId) async {
  DocumentSnapshot document = await Firestore.instance
      .collection('user')
      .document(userId)
      .get();

    return  document['Person Name'];
  );
}
```

**Observação**

Como você não nos informou onde e como é usado o método `getPersonName()` não posso te aconselhar a melhor maneira de usar o método após a modificação que sugeri, então ai você faz os ajustes necessários.

Mas quando for utilizar ele, para pegar o valor sem o future, você terá que fazer a chamada assim

```
Future<void> seuMetodo() async {
  String personName = await getPersonName(idPessoa);
}
```